# Pumpiing Lemma for $0^n1^m0^n$ and $0^{3n}$

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

To understand the Pumping Lemma, I'm going to prove that the language $L = \{0^n1^m0^n | n,m \geq0\}$ is not regular. I choose string $w = 0^{p/2}1^{p/2}0^{p/2}$, for any even number $p$. Clearly $|w| > p$. I use the following decomposition

- $x = 0^{p/2}$
- $y = 1^{p/2}$
- $z = 0^{p/2}$

Clearly for any $i$, $xy^iz \in L$, because the number of $1$s is not important and it doesn't lead to a contradiction. I think there is something I didn't understand about the Lemma. I appreciated it if you let me know why while $L$ is not a regular language, but my decomposition didn't lead to non-regularity.

As another example, consider language $L_1  = \{0 ^{3n} | n \geq 0\}$. This language is clearly regular. I choose $w = 000000$, for $p=3,$ $x=0, y=00, z=000$. It is clear pumping $y$ in for $i=2$ $xy^iz = 00000000 \notin L_1$ while the language is regular. Why I could find a decomposition that shows it is non-regular while the language is regular?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Steven This is exact;y my problem. I appreciate it if you post this hint and clarify the prblem of my proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that a language $L$ is not regular you need to argue that the pumping lemma does not hold. That is, you want to show that **for every** $p$, there **exists** some word $w$ such that, **for every** decomposition of $w$ as $xyz$ with $|xy| \le p$ and $|y| \ge i$, **there exists** some $i \ge 0$ such that $xy^i z \not\in L$.

The quantifiers and their order are critical. What you can do is choose $w$ as a function of $p$. You don't get to choose a specific decomposition $xyz$, so you want to pick a $w$ that will make easy to argue about all possible decompositions.

In you first example $w = 0^{p/2} 1^{p/2} 0^{p/2}$ is not a great choice since there is a way to write $w$ as $xyz$ such tat $xy^i \in L$ for all $i \ge 0$. However, this  doesn't tell you anything about the (non-)regularity of $L$ since there might be other choices of $w$.

Pick, for example, $w = 0^p 1^p 0^p$. Then, all decompositions are of the form $x= 0^{a}$, $y = 0^{b}$, $z=0^{p-a-b}1^p 0^p$, for some $a \ge 0$, $b \ge 1$ with $a+b \le p$. Therefore $xy^iz = 0^{p + (i-1)b} 1^p 0^p$. You can then pick $i=0$ (this is just an example, any $i\neq 1$ works in this case) to get $xy^0z = 0^{p-b}1^p0^p \not\in L$.

---

Conversely, if a language $L$ is regular, then there is **some** $p$, such that all $w \in L$ with $|w|\ge p$ admit **some** decomposition $w=xyz$ such that $xy^iz \in L$ for all $i$.

You don't get to choose the decomposition (as you have done) and, in general, you don't get to choose $p$. The pumping lemma only tells you that some $p$ exists.

Now, in your particular case it happens that the pumping length $p$ of $L$ is actually $3$ (this can be shown by arguing that a DFA with $3$ states can recognize $L$, you can't just blindly fix a value). Your example doesn't work because you picked the wrong decomposition of $w=000000$. Here is a decomposition that satisfies the pumping lemma: $x= \varepsilon$, $y=000$, $z=000$.